# Como inverter a ordem de uma frase?

Tags: java, algoritmo

Tentei fazer um programa que recebe uma frase e retorna a frase na ordem inversa. Exemplo:

Entrada: "Hello, Java!";

Saída: "Java! Hello,";

Tentei fazer, mas não está dando certo.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String line1 = scanner.nextLine();
        String line2 = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] a = line1.split(",");
        
        for(int i=line1.length-1; i >= 0; i--);
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");

        System.out.println(line1);
        System.out.println(line2);
    }
}
```

Comment: o que está acontecendo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem alguns erros aí.

Um deles é que tem um `;` no `for` encerrando o bloco e não executando o que deseja que se repita fazendo com que uma linha solta nem faça sentido porque usa uma variável que só existe dentro do laço.

Também está pegando o tamanho de `line1` quando seu *array* é o `a`.

Não sei o que esse `line2` está fazendo aí, tirei, e tirei as impressões no fim porque elas não parecem ser necessárias pelo problema descrito.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line1 = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] a = line1.split(",");
        for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/tFbJph). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/alimmdlb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/InvertWords.java).

Comment: Entendi !!
Muito Obrigado.

Comment: @MatheusBorba veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.